# After running update via terminal on Ubuntu 13.10 I am getting "Failed to fetch" error msgs. fixes?

Tags: updates

Again, I am using Ubuntu 13.10

```
These are the index files that failed to download: 

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

404 means the files aren't there.
Perhaps the people who put them there made some changes ?

Comment: This is not an answer. Ask your question by clicking on the Ask Question Button